# Java: Displaying preorder and postorder traversals

Tags: java, tree

For the past number of days I've been working on Binary Trees. One task that I seem to have trouble is displaying the preOrderTraversal and postOrderTraversal methods for the BinaryTree class. At the moment, I can only display the  displayInOrder method. What can I do to fix this mistake?

```
public class BinaryTree {
BinaryTreeNode root = null;

public void insertInTree (int newData) {
    if (root == null) 
        root = new BinaryTreeNode(newData);
    else root.insert(newData);
    }


  public void displayInOrder () {
      displayInOrder (root);
  }

  public void preOrderTraversal () {
      preOrderTraversal (root);
  }

  public void postOrderTraversal () {
      postOrderTraversal (root);
  }

  public void preOrderTraversal (BinaryTreeNode subRoot) {
      if (subRoot == null) return;
      preOrderTraversal(subRoot.getLeft());
      System.out.println(" " + subRoot.getData() + " ");
      preOrderTraversal(subRoot.getRight());
  }

  public void postOrderTraversal (BinaryTreeNode subRoot) {
      if (subRoot == null) return;
      postOrderTraversal(subRoot.getLeft());
      System.out.println(" " + subRoot.getData() + " ");
      postOrderTraversal(subRoot.getRight());
  }

  public void displayInOrder (BinaryTreeNode subRoot){
        if (subRoot == null)   return;
        displayInOrder (subRoot.getLeft());
        System.out.print(" " + subRoot.getData() + " ");
        displayInOrder (subRoot.getRight());

  }


  }

public class BinaryTreeNode {
private int data;
private BinaryTreeNode left;
private BinaryTreeNode right;

public BinaryTreeNode() {
    left = null;   right = null; data = 0;
}
public BinaryTreeNode(int data) {
    left = null;   right = null; this.data = data;
}
public int getData() {
    return data;
}
public BinaryTreeNode getLeft() {
    return left;
}
public BinaryTreeNode getRight() {
    return right;
}
public void insert (int newData) {
    if (newData  <  data) {
        if (left == null)
            left = new BinaryTreeNode(newData);
        else left.insert(newData);
    } else if (newData >  data) {
        if (right == null)
            right = new BinaryTreeNode(newData);
        else right.insert(newData);
    } else 
         System.out.println("Duplicate – not adding……" + newData);
}



}




public class BinaryTreeExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree();

    tree.insertInTree(6);
    tree.insertInTree(3);
    tree.insertInTree(9);
    tree.insertInTree(1);
    tree.insertInTree(15);
    tree.insertInTree(7);

    tree.displayInOrder();

}

}
```

Comment: because you only calling this `tree.displayInOrder();` missed other functions calls

Comment: I was able to fix that issue and modify my code. I can display the tree, but the preOrder and postOrder traversals methods being displayed are still wrong. They display, but it's the same order like the displayInOrder method.

Comment: it's not really hard thing , simply i suggest to work on your logic and use debugging to see what is exactly going on in your code

Comment: It's weird. With obviously some help, the methods are now correctly displayed but it's in a weird format. This is what is being displayed http://imgur.com/a/uduO1

Answer (score 0):

Abbreviated traversal definitions:

- "in order" = left, self, right
- "pre order" = self, left, right
- "post order" = left, right, self

Applying that to your code, you just need to move the "print self" line around:

```
public void preOrderTraversal (BinaryTreeNode subRoot) {
    if (subRoot == null) return;
    System.out.print(" " + subRoot.getData() + " ");
    preOrderTraversal(subRoot.getLeft());
    preOrderTraversal(subRoot.getRight());
}

public void postOrderTraversal (BinaryTreeNode subRoot) {
    if (subRoot == null) return;
    postOrderTraversal(subRoot.getLeft());
    postOrderTraversal(subRoot.getRight());
    System.out.print(" " + subRoot.getData() + " ");
}

// already correct
public void displayInOrder (BinaryTreeNode subRoot){
    if (subRoot == null)   return;
    displayInOrder (subRoot.getLeft());
    System.out.print(" " + subRoot.getData() + " ");
    displayInOrder (subRoot.getRight());
}
```

These methods just print the contents. You need to print the final newline in your wrapper methods:

```
public void displayInOrder () {
    displayInOrder (root);
    System.out.println();
}

public void preOrderTraversal () {
    preOrderTraversal (root);
    System.out.println();
}

public void postOrderTraversal () {
    postOrderTraversal (root);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that really helps. One more thing, when it's displayed, it has a weird format. Th displayInOrder displays as 1, 3, 6, 7, 9, 15 but with the preOrderTraversal method, it displays 6 (continuing from 15 on the first line) and then 3, 1, 9, 7, 15 with those numbers being displayed on a separate line. Same thing with postOrderTraversal with 1, 3, 7, 15, 9, 6

Comment: I didn't even notice the print type. See edited answer. FYI I would refactor this to collect the nodes in a list that is passed to the inner methods, then render the list using common code. You could also get fancy by passing lambda for the 3 parts and there by having only one inner method, but that may be going too far.